# Is there such a thing as a "postdoc" for master's degree graduates?

Tags: masters, application, job-search, science

I have recently graduated with an MSc in nuclear physics, and am having a hard time finding appropriate entry-level openings for a job. I have looked at multiple openings at several national laboratories as well as private contractors, but everyone seems to either want a full doctorate for a post-doc position, or a bachelor's/masters with 5+ years of experience. Is there such a thing as a position similar to a post-doc but for master's degree graduates? If so, where could I find such a thing? If not, is there any advice on where to look for openings that I might qualify for?

Comment: For industry positions in particular, it's become a bit of a meme that "years experience" in job "requirements" are completely meaningless. A common example to joke about is when a job says it requires more years experience in a technology than the time that technology has existed (here's the first example I found searching just now: https://twitter.com/tiangolo/status/1281946592459853830 )

Comment: My national lab hires masters folk into technical positions, but you would need to pay attention to the Required vs Desired lists in the posting. If applying to positions requiring a PhD, HR will reject you.

Comment: "Is there such a thing as a position similar to a post-doc but for master's degree graduates?" It's called an internship.

Answer (score 4):

Unlikely. Post docs are academic positions and someone with only an MSc is unlikely to be qualified for any similar position. Postdocs are a way for those with doctorates to get a bit more experience, usually research, so that they can get a more permanent position.

That isn't to say you couldn't be hired by some academic lab as an entry level employee, but it wouldn't be likely to be similar to a postdoc. Postdocs have a certain amount of independence in setting research agendas (not always) that you would be unlikely to have. CERN probably hires quite a lot of technicians. Some experience in field might be valuable. But not a lot of places work at that scale.

If you want to work in academia or a national lab, your best path is probably through a PhD.

Answer (score 2):

Once upon a time labs would hire "research assistants", which someone with a master8s degree would be very competitive for. Such positions do still exist, but as funding levels have diminished in recent years, and numbers of graduate students has gone up, RAs have tended to be the first positions cut from grant proposals, while maintaining postdoc positions. They do still exist though.

Answer (score 1):

We regularly hire masters graduates as research assistants at my institute. We often advertise for a 'postdoc / graduate research assistant' and if the best candidate has a PhD, we have a postdoc, if not, they're hired on a research assistant salary. Often, our research assistants end up transitioning to PhD student and then graduate with a great research portfolio.

Usually this happens if, for example, we need some heavy mathematical analysis done on a medical dataset, but all the PhD-holding applicants are from a biological background and the only one with a maths background is finishing a masters. The maths master is more useful than the biology doctor in that case.